# Adding a single query result into JMeter report

Tags: sql, jdbc, jmeter, report, resultset

I have JMeter plan that starts with a single JDBC sampler query that captures session ID from the Teradata database (`SELECT SESSION;`). Same plan also has large number of JDBC samplers with complicated queries producing large output that I don't want to include in the report.

If I configure summary report and tick `Save Response Data (XML)` then the output from **all** sampler queries will be saved

How do I add only first query result (it's a single integer) into the test summary report and ignore results from all other queries? For example is there a way to set `responseData = false` after the first query output is captured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [sample_variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property can help?

1. Define something in "Variable Names" section of the JDBC Request, i.e. put `session` reference name there like:

   [image]
2. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in Jmeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   sample_variables=session_1
   ```

   or alternatively pass it via `-J` command-line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jsample_variables=session_1 -n -t /path/to/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/results.csv
   ```

   You need to use `session_1` not `session`. As per JDBC Request Sampler documentation:

   > If the Variable Names list is provided, then for each row returned by a Select statement, the variables are set up with the value of the corresponding column (if a variable name is provided), and the count of rows is also set up. For example, if the Select statement returns 2 rows of 3 columns, and the variable list is A,,C, then the following variables will be set up:
   >
   > A_#=2 (number of rows)
   >
   > A_1=column 1, row 1
   >
   > A_2=column 1, row 2
   >
   > C_#=2 (number of rows)
   >
   > C_1=column 3, row 1
   >
   > C_2=column 3, row 2

   So given your query returns only 1 row containing 1 integer - it will live in `session_1` JMeter Variable. See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for comprehensive information on working with database query results in JMeter.
3. When test completes you'll see an extra column in .jtl results file holding your "session" value:

   [image: Sample Variables value]

Comment: Wonderful! This worked handsomely. Enjoy your bounty!

Comment: I also have a related question here, any chance you can take a look, Dmitri? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536508/jmeter-pre-processed-variable-as-part-of-report-file-name

Answer (score 1):

Although not exactly solving your question as posted, I will suggest a workaround, using a "scope" of a listener (i.e. listener will only record items on the same or lower level than a listener itself). Specifically: have **two** Summary Reports: one on the level of test, the other (together with the sampler whose response you want to record) under a controller. For example:

[image]

here I have samplers *1, 2, 3, 4*. I only want to save response data from sampler 2. So

- *Summary Report - Doesn't save responses* is on global level, and it's configured to not save any response data. It only saves what I want to save for all samplers.
- *Summary Report - Saves '2' only* is configured to save response data in XML format. But because this instance of Summary Report is under the same controller as sampler *2*, but other samplers (*1, 3, 4*) are on higher level, it will only record responses of sampler *2*.

So it doesn't exactly allow you to save response data from one sampler into the same file as all other Summary Report data. But at least you can filter which responses you are saving.

Comment: This is great idea and I don't even need a controller, I can simply attach summary report to the JDBC sampler that executes my session query. However the prize goes to Dmitri's answer

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try assertion for ${__threadNum}

i.e. set condition for assertion as "${__threadNum}=1" and set your listner's "Log/display only" option as "successes"

This way it should log only the first response from samplers.