# JMeter pre-processed variable as part of report file name

Tags: sql, variables, jdbc, jmeter

In my test plan I have JDBC PreProcessor that captures a single value that I'm trying to save into a variable. Then I want to reuse this variable as part of summary report's file name.

I wonder if creating that creating that variable happens too late because I always get literal value `logs/${session_id_1}-summary.cvs` rather than `logs/1234-summary.cvs`

I'm also not sure if I need to use `resultVariable` or `variableNames` to store the value. So far I tried different combinations with no luck

Then I'm also not clear at which point I should attach the pre-processor, to the first sampler?

Here's my latest (short) version of JMX:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.9" jmeter="3.0 r1743807">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="TPCDS Benchmark Test Plan TPG Flavor" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="JDBC Users" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1370729701000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1370729701000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <JDBCDataSource guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JDBCDataSource" testname="JDBC_Configuration_tpcds" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="autocommit">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="checkQuery">Select 1</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="connectionAge">5000</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="dataSource">jdbcConfig_tpcds</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="dbUrl">jdbc:teradata://${TDPID}/database=tpcds</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="driver">com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="keepAlive">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="password">tpcds</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="poolMax">10</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="timeout">10000</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="transactionIsolation">DEFAULT</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="trimInterval">60000</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="username">tpcds</stringProp>
        </JDBCDataSource>
        <hashTree/>
        <Arguments guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
            <elementProp name="TDPID" elementType="Argument">
              <stringProp name="Argument.name">TDPID</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(target_dbs)}</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <elementProp name="DBC_USERNAME" elementType="Argument">
              <stringProp name="Argument.name">DBC_USERNAME</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(dbc_username,dbc)}</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <elementProp name="DBC_PASSWORD" elementType="Argument">
              <stringProp name="Argument.name">DBC_PASSWORD</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(dbc_password,dbc)}</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
          </collectionProp>
        </Arguments>
        <hashTree/>
        <JDBCSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JDBCSampler" testname="query1" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="dataSource">jdbcConfig_tpcds</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="query">${__FileToString(sql/query1.sql)}</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryArguments"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryArgumentsTypes"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryType">Select Statement</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="resultVariable"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="variableNames"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryTimeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="resultSetHandler">Store as String</stringProp>
        </JDBCSampler>
        <hashTree>
          <JDBCPreProcessor guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JDBCPreProcessor" testname="Session PreProcessor" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="dataSource">jdbcConfig_tpcds</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="query">SELECT SESSION as session_id;</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="queryArguments"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="queryArgumentsTypes"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="queryTimeout"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="queryType">Select Statement</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="resultSetHandler">Store as String</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="resultVariable">session_id</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="variableNames">session_id</stringProp>
          </JDBCPreProcessor>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="SummaryReport" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Summary Report" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>false</assertions>
              <subresults>false</subresults>
              <responseData>true</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>true</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename">logs/${session_id_1}-summary.xml</stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing filenames of Listeners test elements on the fly is not really supported in JMeter as Listeners are being initialized **before** any variables. The recommended way is:

1. Get your Terradata session id **outside of JMeter**, i.e. using [BTEQ](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/teradata/teradata_bteq.htm) or equivalent
2. Pass the value to JMeter via -J command line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jsession_id_1=1234 -n -t /path/to/testplan.jmx
   ```
3. Refer the session id value via [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function where required as

   ```
   ${__P(session_id_1,)}
   ```

---

If for any reason you still need to do it inside JMeter test script, here is a possible solution, however keep in mind the following:

1. You need to remove **everything** from "Filename" input of the Summary Report listener. Just let it be blank.
2. Make sure that below code is executed **only once** and with only one thread.

So:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the `query1` sampler and **after** the `Session PreProcessor`
2. Select `groovy` in the "Language" drop-down
3. Put the following code into JSR223 PostProcessor "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
   import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
   import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
   import org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass;

   import java.lang.reflect.Field;
   import java.lang.reflect.Method;

   StandardJMeterEngine engine = ctx.getEngine();
   Field test = engine.getClass().getDeclaredField("test");
   test.setAccessible(true);
   HashTree testPlanTree = (HashTree) test.get(engine);        

   SearchByClass summaryReportsSearch = new SearchByClass(ResultCollector.class);
   testPlanTree.traverse(summaryReportsSearch);
   Collection summaryReports = summaryReportsSearch.getSearchResults();
   ResultCollector summaryReport = summaryReports.iterator().next();

   Class [] fileNameParam = new Class[1];
   fileNameParam[0] = String.class;

   Method setFileName = summaryReport.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setFilenameProperty", fileNameParam);
   setFileName.setAccessible(true);
   setFileName.invoke(summaryReport, new String(vars.get("session_id_1")));

   Method init = summaryReport.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("initializeFileOutput");
   init.setAccessible(true);
   init.invoke(summaryReport);
   ```

If you're using JMeter 3.0 - groovy is bundled. For previous JMeter versions you will need to install groovy language support manually, check out [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article for groovy engine installation instructions and scripting best practices.

Comment: I'm not sure that 1st solution will work though. What I'm trying to do is to output all the test queries I'm executing into the file that bears the session ID. So I pretty much need to be on the single (same) thread that connects to db and obtains the session ID. I'll try your 2nd suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use a variable as part of a summary report file name as a variable exist per User thread and after summary report has been initialized.

Use property instead:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

Comment: Pre-defined property helps me none. I'm trying to name my report using piece of information I obtain dynamically at runtime. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: you can pass this property at runtime using -J option. From what information do you build it ? if session_id I don't think you can

Comment: Simple SQL query that gets session id from the database. See my code example

Comment: Basically I need to have one report from each thread of execution which in my case will also have same JDBC connection