# How to print timestamp/different name in Jmeter test results csv

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a performance test plan in Jmeter. As a constant running test plan, I need to generate execution summary in CSV format with a timestamp.

In the View Result Tree, I have provided a csv filename with timestamp variable as '${__time(YYYY-MM-DD-SS,time)}' (Please see image below). But this doesn't work for me as it is not generating any files after the run.

[image]

Or is there any way we can generate summary report csv with different name for each run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter pre-processed variable as part of report file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536508/jmeter-pre-processed-variable-as-part-of-report-file-name)

Answer (score 2):

It is [not recommended to use Listeners for anything but tests development and/or debugging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/), they don't add any value and consume a lot of resources because all the [thread context](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) is being passed to the listener when any [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) occurs.

So I would recommend:

1. Removing all listeners from your test plan
2. Run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
3. If you need to include the timestamp into the .jtl results file you can use Windows [date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/date) and/or [time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/time) commands

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l %date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%.csv
   ```
4. You can control what is being stored in the .jtl results file using properties responsible for the [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

Comment: I know running Jmeter in CLI mode would be more resource friendly. But currently we need to run it in GUI mode due to project requirement. When we run GUI mode, we need to change the file name every time.

Do you know how to generate csv with different name for each run. Please let me know.